# Java application to extract data from DB based on user filter conditions

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

i would like to create a web application in java where the users selects the filter condition like order placed for a period of time/order placed for a particular location /order placed for a particular service ,based on the condition the data needs to be extracted from database. I can create the backend java class files to extract the data from DB but dont know about how to pass the filter condition from front end jsp/servlets. Can anyone provide me an example of how to achieve this ?

Comment: No hard feelings buddy, but this is not the right place for such question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement a (in this case REST) webservice with a database connection is probably by using [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/) and hibernate (it's the standard object-relational mapping tool in Spring). Simply process the request with the required variables in a @RestController and process them in a transactional @Service class like this (I will use the media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded in this example for the variables sent by the client):

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    Service service; //Service needs to be an interface in order to be autowired

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/insertTheUrlYouWantToUse", 
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Response> yourMethod(@RequestParam String var1, 
            @RequestParam String var2){
        //Your code here
        //Example code:
        Response r = service.process(var1, var2); //Response would be your custom class. 
                                                  //Of course you can use any other 
                                                  //existing class if it fits your needs
        return new ResponseEntity<Response>(r, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The Service interface is needed so that the "real" service class can be autowired by spring:

```
public interface UpdateService {

    Response process(String var1, String var2);
}
```

ServiceImpl would be the "real" class. It has to be transactional to be able to make database connections. I am only going to work with one database entity called "Entity" (how creative i am, right?)

```
@Service
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em; //needed for all the database related stuff

    public Response process(String var1, String var2){
        try{
            Entity entity = em
            .createQuery("FROM Entity WHERE var1=:var1 AND var2=:var2", Entity.class)
            .setParameter("var1", var1).setParameter("var2", var2).getSingleResult();
        }catch(NoResultException e){
            //whatever you want to do if no entity is available
        }
        return new Response(Entity); //return the result to the Controller, depending on
                                     //you Response you can obviously add messages, links
                                     //and other stuff if you like
    }
}
```

To complete this, an Entity would look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TableNameInDatabase")
public class Entity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String var1;

    @Column(name="someValue")
    private String var2;

    //add getter, setter and constructor (too lazy for that)
}
```

You should be able to call on "[http://yourHostname:yourPort/insertTheUrlYouWantToUse?var1=someValue&var2=someOtherValue](http://www.notawebsite.com/)"
I am not going to write the class Response here... since its pretty much up to you how you design it. When the constructor returns a ResponseEntity with your custom Response, all the variables in the Response will be converted to xml when the client receives it. If you implement your client with Spring as well, you can make it expect the same Reponse object and keep working with it on the client side. Hope I could answer your question in some way. If you don't want to use Spring Boot, then I am sure that there are equivalent libraries/frameworks out there which will work in a somewhat similar way.

Comment: I just saw this is marked as Javascript, sry if i kinda missed the point here, maybe it can still be helpful^^